# Embeddable, Embedded

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I would like to achieve nesting an element notated as Embeddable which already has embedded elements:

```
@Embeddable
public class A implements Serializable {

private int a;
private int b;
}

@Embeddable
public class B implements Serializable {

@Embedded
protected A sum;
@Embedded
protected A value;
```

...
}

```
@Entity
public class C implements Serializable{
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "sum.a", column =
    @Column(name = "SUM_COL_A", precision = 12, scale = 2, nullable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "sum.b", column =
    @Column(name = "SUM_COL_B", precision = 12, scale = 2, nullable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value.a", column =
    @Column(name = "VALUE_COL_A", precision = 12, scale = 2, nullable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value.b", column =
    @Column(name = "VALUE_COL_B", precision = 12, scale = 2, nullable = false))
private B property;
})
}
```

After execution, I have two columns created (VALUE_COL_A and VALUE_COL_B) and the first two columns does not exist at all.

What am I missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct.  It may be a bug in your persistence provider.  Check if you are on the latest release/patch, or log a bug.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the B property is serialized and there are no sub-embedded objects. So there should be only a single column with all of the contents of B in it. You will not be able to search on any of the attributes of the embedded B object, just FYI.